# Full text query slow on first run

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have SQL Server database which has size of 65GB and 6 million rows. We have essays in tables and the average size of an essay is 450 words. When I run a query for the first time, it takes 3-10 seconds to show me the results. On running same query again, it is in less than 1 second (very fast).

Please let me know how to optimize it so I can get queries in less than 1 sec.

Query example:

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM tblContent WHERE CONTAINS(pagecontent,'"increasing the likelihood"')
```

Here is detail of server(VPS):

- OS: Windows Server 2012
- SQL Server 2012 Enterprise (Trial)
- Processor: set to 0
- Memory: set to 0
- RAM: 4GB
- Processor: QUAD 4Ghz

Comment: **RAM: 4GB** running a 65GB database ... Move to a better hardware !

Comment: Or just buy some RAM.

Comment: How much RAM is required for database of 65GB. The SQL Server 2012 enterprise need 2GB RAM(recommended) but I have 4GB

Comment: Do you happen to have a table definition at hand?  Then please insert it into your question.  And how about the indexes?  Do you have any?  Also, the query plan could help a lot.  If you tell us these details I am sure that the public will vote for reopening your question.

Answer (score 5):

> *When I run a query for the first time, it takes 3-10 seconds to show me the results. On running same query again, it is in less than 1 second (very fast)*

The second time you run the query, it is likely that data and index pages for the relational tables are coming from SQL Server's cache rather than being read in from disk. Likewise, the full-text portion of the processing will also benefit from caching.

As the comments on the question indicate, 4GB does not seem like very much memory for a SQL Server managing a 65GB database. More physical memory will allow SQL Server to cache a greater proportion of your relational tables and full-text indexed data.

The exact amount you need depends on the nature of your workload, and the response times your users expect. I would imagine that expanding the memory even modestly (say to 8 or 16GB) would result in a very noticeable performance improvement, and more predictable response times overall.

You would also want to configure the maximum memory for SQL Server to ensure there is enough for Windows as well. See the following links for more information on memory (and other important details):

[How much memory does my SQL Server actually need?](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/how-much-memory-does-my-sql-server-actually-need/)

[Troubleshooting SQL Server: A Guide for the Accidental DBA (free eBook)](https://www.simple-talk.com/books/sql-books/troubleshooting-sql-server-a-guide-for-the-accidental-dba/)